# Counting Occurrences of Letter Combinations

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of each letter combination in a text file:

*'aa', 'ab',...'zy', 'zz'*

I have managed to be able to count the occurrence of single letters easily enough using collections.Counter and am just wondering if there is a similar approach for 2 letter combinations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the letters, you can filter the non alphas, you don't need to store any extra data in memory, all you have to do is chain the chars and keep track of the previous char each time:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

with open("in.txt") as f:
    prev = f.read(1)
    c = Counter()
    for ch in filter(str.isalpha, chain.from_iterable(f)):
        c[prev + ch] += 1
        prev = ch
print(c)
```

If you want all chars just remove the filter:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    prev = f.read(1)
    c = Counter()
    for ch in chain.from_iterable(f):
        c[prev + ch] += 1
        prev = ch
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import collections, itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

text = "I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of each letter combination in a text file"

counter = collections.Counter(pairwise(text))
```

The "trick" is to use a generator, like the one I copied from the python documents, to access the letter combinations. It can be extended naturally to three or more letters.

If you want to ignore the white spaces, tokenize the input first.

Comment: Why not just `Counter(pairwise(text))`?

Comment: Good idea. I incorporated your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

txt = "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

txt1 = txt[:-1]
txt2 = txt[1:]
print (Counter([t1+t2 for t1, t2 in zip(txt1,txt2)]))
```